# Control the Activity of a shared folder in Drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

I would like to control the activity of a shared folder that I have in Google Drive.

I am using the Google Drive Activity API to see the real-time information of the files but I came across two problems:

- I can only see the modifications in the folder made by me and not by the others. (I suppose there's something about the 2AuthClient token)
- I can't get to know if a file was renamed or not (which is not that important at the moment)

I was thinking that maybe a solution would be to ask that each account that has access to the folder to create an Auth2Client token and send it to me. After that run a function for each person who sends their token, the problem I see with that is the simple act of sharing a token which is personal and private but also the fact of doing multiple functions with the same code inside is not very logical.

Has anyone faced the same problem and found a solution?

My code is from the Developpers Google platform: [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/quickstart/nodejs)

And even if in the code it's supposed to get the ActorInfo, it only gives **me** as the actor because it only sees my modifications and not the other modifications.

Or even if someone knows another way to achieve this task (maybe without google drive activity API) it will be very helpfull. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tested on my Google domain account and I am getting modifications from all users as expected. I assume you added `'itemName': 'items/ITEM_ID'` in your query where `ITEM_ID` is your shared folder, right?

Comment: @Emel Where's this query? It is in the code provided by the platform or I need to add it? Can you specify it please? I'm very new with this, thanks

Comment: @Emel I added de const params = {"ancestor_name":"items/ITEM_ID"} which after that I send the service.activity.query{requestBody:params} but is not working with people outside the domain

Comment: In the [Request Body](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query#request-body), line 77 of the quick start example (params), you have to add the ID of the resource from which you want the activities.

Comment: `but is not working with people outside the domain`, that is odd, I just tested with a person outside of my Domain and is working as expected. Remember that the correct parameter is `ancestorName` no `ancestor_name`, after that change, works for you?

Comment: You were right thanks! Now I can see the activity of other people, just one more question, when someone changes something I get people/ACCOUNT_ID (I suppose), is there a way to see the name of the account who changed it (like "Rick ...")

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`People API`](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs) to retrieve the desired information. I am posting the solution as an answer, please consider voting/accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the activities to determined resources you have to add one of the following parameters as a union field `key`: `itemName` or `ancestorName`. The default is `ancestorName : items/root` if no key is specified

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query#request-body):

| Fields |  |
| --- | --- |
| itemName | **string** |
|  | Return activities for this Drive item. The format is `items/ITEM_ID`. |
| ancestorName | **string** |
|  | Return activities for this Drive folder and all children and descendants. The format is `items/ITEM_ID`. |

In your case, as you want to query for a determined shared folder, you should add this inside the Request Body:

```js
const param = {"ancestorName" : "items/<folder_id>"}
```

###### Documentation:

- [Node.js driveactivity library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/driveactivity/classes/Driveactivity.html)
- [Activity query](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query)